# DataTable Cells Dynamic Content

Tags: jquery, if-statement, datatable

I'm working on a DataTable that has buttons to choose what to do with each row.  However, the buttons vary based on the string value of another one of the cells.  This is the code I use to populate the tables:

```
var table = $('#CheckRegisterTable').dataTable({
            'ajax': {
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("GetData", "CheckRegister")',
                //data: function (d) {

                //}
            },
            columns: [
            {
                data:   "select",
                render: function ( data, type, row ) {
                    if ( type === 'display' ) {
                        return '<input type="checkbox" class="editor-active">';
                    }
                    return data;
                },
                sortable: false,
                className: "text-center"
            },
            {
                data: 'checkNo',
                sortable: true,
                className: "text-center"
            },
            {
                data: 'studentID',
                sortable: true,
                className: "text-center"
            },
            {
                data: 'ssn',
                sortable: true,
                className: "text-center"
            },
            {
                data: 'payee',
                sortable: true,
                className: "text-center"
            },
            {
                data: 'date',
                sortable: true,
                className: "text-center"
            },
            {
                data: 'type',
                sortable: true,
                className: "text-center"
            },
            {
                data: 'amount',
                sortable: true,
                className: "text-right"
            },
            {
                data: 'status',
                sortable: true,
                className: "text-center"
            },
            {
                render: function (data) {
                    var row = table.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();
                    if (row[8] == "Printed") {
                        return '<button><i class="fa-fa-reply"></button><i class="fa-fa-rotate-left"><button><i class="fa-fa-close"></button><button><i class="fa-fa-print"></button><button><i class="fa-fa-info"></button>'
                    }
                    else if (row[8] == "Cleared") {
                        return '<button><i class="fa-fa-info"></button>'
                    }
                    else if (row[8] == "Stopped") {
                        return '<button><i class="fa-fa-rotate-left"></button><button><i class="fa-fa-close"></button><button><i class="fa-fa-info"></button>'
                    }
                    else if (row[8] == "Reissued") {
                        return '<button><i class="fa-fa-reply"></button><button><i class="fa-fa-rotate-left"></button><button><i class="fa-fa-close"></button><button><i class="fa-fa-info"></button>'
                    }
                    else if (row[8] == "Returned") {
                        return '<button><i class="fa-fa-rotate-left"></button><button><i class="fa-fa-info"></button>'
                    }
                    else if (row[8] == "Reissue Pending") {
                        return '<button><i class="fa-fa-rotate-left"></button><button><i class="fa-fa-info"></button>'
                    }
                    else if (row[8] == "Stop Pending") {
                        return '<button><i class="fa-fa-close"></button><button><i class="fa-fa-info"></button>'
                    }

                }

            }
            ],
            ordering: true,
            order: [0, 'Name'],
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true
        });
```

But the code is giving me errors, and I'm not even sure I'm doing it right.  What's the best way to look at the value in the 'status' column and populate the other column with the buttons?
Thanks for your help!

Edit:
My View File (this has been edited since the original post):

```
<link href="~/Content/checkRegister.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Check Register";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<br /> <br /><br />
<div class="container-fluid left">
<div class="container-fluid left">
    <table id="CheckRegisterTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover text-nowrap">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><input type="checkbox" class="editor-active"></th>
                <th data-column="checkNo" class="text-left" id="TDtooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Check Number" data-container="body">Check Number</th>
                <th data-column="studentID" class="text-left" id="TDtooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Student ID Number" data-container="body">Student ID</th>
                <th data-column="ssn" class="text-left" id="TDtooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Social Security Number" data-container="body">SSN</th>
                <th data-column="payee" class="text-left" id="TDtooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Payee Name" data-container="body">Payee</th>
                <th data-column="date" class="text-left" id="TDtooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Check Date" data-container="body">Date</th>
                <th data-column="type" class="text-left" id="TDtooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Check Type" data-container="body">Type</th>
                <th data-column="amount" class="text-left" id="TDtooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Check Amount" data-container="body">Amount</th>
                <th data-column="status" class="text-left" id="TDtooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Check Status" data-container="body">Status</th>
                <th data-column="status" class="text-left" id="TDtooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Action" data-container="body">Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
</div>

@section scripts
{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/dataTables")

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.extend($.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
            'pagingType': 'full_numbers',
            'pageLength': 25,
            'language': {
                'paginate': {
                    'first': '&laquo;',
                    'last': '&raquo;',
                    'previous': '&lsaquo;',
                    'next': '&rsaquo;'
                },
                'info': 'Displaying _START_-_END_ of _TOTAL_',
                'infoEmpty': 'Displaying 0 to 0 of 0',
                'infoFiltered': '',
                'search': '',
                'zeroRecords': 'No matching records found'
            },
            //'dom':<"top"f>rt<"bottom"<"pull-left"l><"pull-right"i>p<"clear">>',
            'dom': '<"top"f>rt<"bottom"<"pull-left"l><"pull-right"i>p<"clear">>',
            'initComplete': function (settings, json) {
                $('.dataTables_filter input[type=search]').attr('placeholder', 'Search');
            }
        });


        $(document).ready(function () {
            var table = $('#CheckRegisterTable').dataTable({
                'ajax': {
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetData", "CheckRegister")',
                    //data: function (d) {

                    //}
                },
                columns: [
                {
                    data: "select",
                    render: function (data, type, row) {
                        if (type === 'display') {
                            return '<input type="checkbox" class="editor-active">';
                        }
                        return data;
                    },
                    sortable: false,
                    className: "text-center"
                },
                {
                    data: 'checkNo',
                    sortable: true,
                    className: "text-center"
                },
                {
                    data: 'studentID',
                    sortable: true,
                    className: "text-center"
                },
                {
                    data: 'ssn',
                    sortable: true,
                    className: "text-center"
                },
                {
                    data: 'payee',
                    sortable: true,
                    className: "text-center"
                },
                {
                    data: 'date',
                    sortable: true,
                    className: "text-center"
                },
                {
                    data: 'type',
                    sortable: true,
                    className: "text-center"
                },
                {
                    data: 'amount',
                    sortable: true,
                    className: "text-right"
                },
                {
                    data: 'status',
                    sortable: true,
                    className: "text-center"
                },
                {
                    data: 'status',
                    render: function (data, type, row) {
                        //var row = table.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();
                        if ( data == "Printed") {
                            return '<button><i class="fa-fa-reply"></button><i class="fa-fa-rotate-left"><button><i class="fa-fa-close"></button><button><i class="fa-fa-print"></button><button><i class="fa-fa-info"></button>';
                        }
                        else if (data == "Cleared") {
                            return '<button><i class="fa-fa-info"></button>';
                        }
                        else if (data == "Stopped") {
                            return '<button><i class="fa-fa-rotate-left"></button><button><i class="fa-fa-close"></button><button><i class="fa-fa-info"></button>';
                        }
                        else if (data == "Reissued") {
                            return '<button><i class="fa-fa-reply"></button><button><i class="fa-fa-rotate-left"></button><button><i class="fa-fa-close"></button><button><i class="fa-fa-info"></button>';
                        }
                        else if (data == "Returned") {
                            return '<button><i class="fa-fa-rotate-left"></button><button><i class="fa-fa-info"></button>';
                        }
                        else if (data == "Reissue Pending") {
                            return '<button><i class="fa-fa-rotate-left"></button><button><i class="fa-fa-info"></button>';
                        }
                        else if (data == "Stop Pending") {
                            return '<button><i class="fa-fa-close"></button><button><i class="fa-fa-info"></button>';
                        }
                    },
                    sortable: false,
                    className: "text-center"
                }
                ],
                ordering: true,
                order: [0, 'Name'],
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true
            });
        });

        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
            delay: 0,
            track: true,
            fade: 100
        });
    </script>
}
```

Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using SAAS.Models;
using SAAS.Services;

namespace SAAS.Controllers
{
    public class CheckRegisterController : Controller
    {
        // GET: CheckRegister
        public ActionResult CheckRegister()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public JsonResult GetData(DTParameters dtModel, FilterViewModel filterModel)
        {
            try
            {
                List<CheckRegister> data = new CheckRegisterService().GetCheckRegisters(dtModel.Start, dtModel.Length);
                int count = new CheckRegisterService().Count();
                DTResult<CheckRegister> result = new DTResult<CheckRegister>
                {
                    draw = dtModel.Draw,
                    data = data,
                    recordsFiltered = count,
                    recordsTotal = count
                };
                return Json(result);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(new {error = ex.Message});
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Model:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace SAAS.Models
{
    public class CheckRegister
    {
        public CheckRegister(string CheckNo, string StudentID, string SSN, string Payee, string Date, string Type, string Amount, string Status)
        {
            checkNo = CheckNo;
            studentID = StudentID;
            ssn = SSN;
            payee = Payee;
            date = Date;
            type = Type;
            amount = Amount;
            status = Status;
        }

        [Key]
        public string checkNo { get; set; }
        public string studentID { get; set; }
        public string ssn { get; set; }
        public string payee { get; set; }
        public string date { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string amount { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Service:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using SAAS.Models;

namespace SAAS.Services
{
    public class CheckRegisterService
    {
        private static readonly List<CheckRegister> CheckRegisters;

        static CheckRegisterService()
        {
            CheckRegisters = new List<CheckRegister>
            {
                new CheckRegister("1234567890", "69489", "123-45-6789", "Harry Potter", "12/10/2014", "Termination", "$5,000.00", "Printed"),
                new CheckRegister("4561237890", "53191", "987-65-4321", "Hermione Granger", "12/1/2014", "Bonus", "$300.00", "Cleared"),
                new CheckRegister("6543217890", "84148", "651-47-3892", "Ron Weasley", "12/1/2014", "Allotment", "$150.00", "Stopped"),
                new CheckRegister("7987654321", "71258", "456-78-9123", "Hogwarts School", "12/1/2014", "Allotment", "$300.00", "Returned"),
                new CheckRegister("8987654329", "69460", "731-61-8731", "Draco Maifoy", "12/1/2014", "Allotment", "$1,000.00", "Reissued"),
                new CheckRegister("9987654321", "52538", "290-97-2939", "Vincent Crabbe", "12/1/2014", "Allotment", "$300.00", "Reissue Pending"),
                new CheckRegister("9987654329", "57716", "336-92-7381", "Gegory Goyle", "12/1/2014", "Allotment", "$300.00", "Stop Pending"),
                new CheckRegister("9987654320", "52531", "290-97-2939", "Vincent Croub", "12/2/2014", "Allotment", "$310.00", "Reissue Pending"),
                new CheckRegister("9987654322", "52532", "290-97-2532", "JJ Hardy", "12/3/2014", "Allotment", "$301.00", "Reissue Pending"),
                new CheckRegister("9987654323", "52533", "290-97-6424", "Adam Levine", "12/4/2014", "Allotment", "$34.00", "Reissue Pending"),
                new CheckRegister("9987654324", "52534", "290-97-1632", "Blake Shelton", "12/5/2014", "Allotment", "$330.00", "Reissue Pending"),
                new CheckRegister("9987654325", "52535", "290-42-1324", "Nick Jonas", "12/6/2014", "Allotment", "$350.00", "Reissue Pending"),
                new CheckRegister("9987654326", "52536", "290-53-3539", "Chris Davis", "12/7/2014", "Allotment", "$360.00", "Reissue Pending"),
                new CheckRegister("9987654327", "52537", "325-23-5532", "Chris Tillman", "12/8/2014", "Allotment", "$370.00", "Reissue Pending"),
                new CheckRegister("9987654328", "52539", "290-31-6883", "Manny Machado", "12/9/2014", "Allotment", "$380.00", "Reissue Pending"),
            };
        }

        public List<CheckRegister> GetCheckRegisters(int start, int length)
        {
            return FilterCheckRegisters().Skip(start).Take(length).ToList();
            //return CheckRegisters.ToList();
        }

        public int Count()
        {
            return FilterCheckRegisters().Count();
        }

        public IQueryable<CheckRegister> FilterCheckRegisters()
        {
            IQueryable<CheckRegister> results = CheckRegisters.AsQueryable();

            return results;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If it comes down to it, you could make the ajax call, return the data, build the html table yourself then call `dataTable()` on the built table

Comment: @DelightedD0D how exactly would I go about doing that?  I'm fairly new at using DataTables...

Comment: Can you post an example of the json you get back from your ajax call?

Comment: @DelightedD0D how do I see the json?  Sorry, I feel really dumb for not knowing that!

Comment: If you can drop the button stuff and get the table to load normally do this, 1) in chrome, open the developer tools, 2) click "Network", 3) find and click the ajax call from the list, 4) click "Response" and copy the json data  http://i.imgur.com/G7ruq9w.png , actually, you should be able to see theresponse even if the table isnt loading

Comment: @DelightedD0D I gave it awhile to go through everything, because it seemed to still be working, but all it returned was a list pointing to the same thing, which was not an ajax...

Comment: Is your table being created at all?

Comment: @DelightedD0D just saw this... yes, it's being created, It's just giving me the error that points to datatables.net/tn/4 and giving me null values in the last column

Comment: Is your page viewable online somewhere?

Comment: @DelightedD0D no, sorry

Comment: Word, we can probably get it working for you but we'll need to see a sample of the data you're working with (at least I would to be able to help)

Comment: @DelightedD0D okay, cool!  Give me a minute, I'll post my Controller, View, Model, and Services file in the original post!  Thanks for your help, I know it's possible, but I can't figure out what's going on, it's driving me crazy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below should work for you:

[Here is a test page showing how this works](http://dodsoftware.com/sotests/dtTest/dtTest.html) it doesnt use MVC but you'll get the idea

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

    $('#CheckRegisterTable').dataTable( {

           'ajax': {
               type: 'POST',
               url: '@Url.Action("GetData", "CheckRegister")',
            },
            columns: [
            {
                 // data: "select",  // commenting out since your object doesnt seem to have a 'select' property                
                render: function (data, type, row ) {
                    if ( type === 'display' ) {
                        return '<input type="checkbox" class="editor-active">';
                    }
                    return ''; // changed from `return data;` since your object doesnt seem to have a 'select' property
                },
                sortable: false,
                className: "text-center" 
            },
            {
                data: 'checkNo',
                sortable: true,
                className: "text-center"
            },
            {
                data: 'studentID',
                "sortable": true,
                className: "text-center"
            },
            {
                data: 'ssn',
                sortable: true,
                className: "text-center"
            },
            {
                data: 'payee',
                sortable: true,
                className: "text-center"
            },
            {
                data: 'date',
                sortable: true,
                className: "text-center"
            },
            {
                data: 'type',
                sortable: true,
                className: "text-center"
            },
            {
                data: 'amount',
                sortable: true,
                className: "text-right"
            },
            {
                data: 'status',
                sortable: true,
                className: "text-center"
            },
            {
                render: function (data, type, row) {
                    // row is an object not an  array, change the below to use dot notation like `row.status` not `row[8]`
                    if (row.status == "Printed") {
                        return '<button><i class="fa-fa-reply"></button><i class="fa-fa-rotate-left"><button><i class="fa-fa-close"></button><button><i class="fa-fa-print"></button><button><i class="fa-fa-info"></button>'
                    }
                    else if (row.status == "Cleared") {
                        return '<button><i class="fa-fa-info"></button>'
                    }
                    else if (row.status == "Stopped") {
                        return '<button><i class="fa-fa-rotate-left"></button><button><i class="fa-fa-close"></button><button><i class="fa-fa-info"></button>'
                    }
                    else if (row.status == "Reissued") {
                        return '<button><i class="fa-fa-reply"></button><button><i class="fa-fa-rotate-left"></button><button><i class="fa-fa-close"></button><button><i class="fa-fa-info"></button>'
                    }
                    else if (row.status == "Returned") {
                        return '<button><i class="fa-fa-rotate-left"></button><button><i class="fa-fa-info"></button>'
                    }
                    else if (row.status == "Reissue Pending") {
                        return '<button><i class="fa-fa-rotate-left"></button><button><i class="fa-fa-info"></button>'
                    }
                    else if (row.status == "Stop Pending") {
                        return '<button><i class="fa-fa-close"></button><button><i class="fa-fa-info"></button>'
                    }
                }
            }
            ],
            ordering: true, 
            order: [ [0, 'asc'] ], // pretty sure this should be a nested array like [ [ column index, sortorder] ] 
            processing: true, // not sure if you need this
            serverSide: true  // not sure if you need this
    } );  

} );
```

Comment: sad the sample link below not working anymore

Answer (score 0):

Data table declaration should be under `$(document).ready`, also `render: function (data, type, row)` is part of columns definition. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var table = $('#CheckRegisterTable').dataTable({
                'ajax': {
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetData", "CheckRegister")',
                    //data: function (d) {

                    //}
                },
                columns: [
                {
                    data:   "select",
                    render: function ( data, type, row ) {
                        if ( type === 'display' ) {
                            return '<input type="checkbox" class="editor-active">';
                        }
                        return data;
                    },
                    sortable: false,
                    className: "text-center"
                },
                {
                    data: 'checkNo',
                    sortable: true,
                    className: "text-center"
                },
                {
                    data: 'studentID',
                    sortable: true,
                    className: "text-center"
                },
                {
                    data: 'ssn',
                    sortable: true,
                    className: "text-center"
                },
                {
                    data: 'payee',
                    sortable: true,
                    className: "text-center"
                },
                {
                    data: 'date',
                    sortable: true,
                    className: "text-center"
                },
                {
                    data: 'type',
                    sortable: true,
                    className: "text-center"
                },
                {
                    data: 'amount',
                    sortable: true,
                    className: "text-right"
                },
                {
                    data: 'status',
                    sortable: true,
                    className: "text-center",
                    render: function (data, type, row) {
                        //var row = table.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();
                        if (row[8] == "Printed") {
                            return '<button><i class="fa-fa-reply"></button><i class="fa-fa-rotate-left"><button><i class="fa-fa-close"></button><button><i class="fa-fa-print"></button><button><i class="fa-fa-info"></button>'
                        }
                        else if (row[8] == "Cleared") {
                            return '<button><i class="fa-fa-info"></button>'
                        }
                        else if (row[8] == "Stopped") {
                            return '<button><i class="fa-fa-rotate-left"></button><button><i class="fa-fa-close"></button><button><i class="fa-fa-info"></button>'
                        }
                        else if (row[8] == "Reissued") {
                            return '<button><i class="fa-fa-reply"></button><button><i class="fa-fa-rotate-left"></button><button><i class="fa-fa-close"></button><button><i class="fa-fa-info"></button>'
                        }
                        else if (row[8] == "Returned") {
                            return '<button><i class="fa-fa-rotate-left"></button><button><i class="fa-fa-info"></button>'
                        }
                        else if (row[8] == "Reissue Pending") {
                            return '<button><i class="fa-fa-rotate-left"></button><button><i class="fa-fa-info"></button>'
                        }
                        else if (row[8] == "Stop Pending") {
                            return '<button><i class="fa-fa-close"></button><button><i class="fa-fa-info"></button>'
                        }

                    }

                }
                ],
                ordering: true,
                order: [0, 'Name'],
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true
            });
    });
```